# Swift 3 NSDictionary to Dictionary conversion causes NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, json, swift3, nsdictionary

I have just converted my project from Swift **2.2 to 3.0**, and I'm getting a new exception thrown in my tests.  I have some Objective C code in one of my tests which reads in some JSON from a file:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)getJSONDictionaryFromFile:(NSString *)filename {
    /* some code which checks the parameter and gets a string of JSON from a file.
     * I've checked in the debugger, and jsonString is properly populated. */

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
    return jsonDict;
}
```

I'm calling this from some Swift code:

```
let expectedResponseJSON = BZTestCase.getJSONDictionary(fromFile: responseFileName)
```

This works just fine *most* of the time, but I have one `JSON` file which causes the error:

```
failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[__NSSingleObjectArrayI enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000201fa0"
```

The strange thing about this is that the error is generated after the `getJSONDictionaryFromFile` method returns and before `expectedResponseJSON` in the Swift code is populated.  To me, this seems to say that it's the conversion from an `NSDictionary` to `Dictionary` which is the problem.  The offending JSON file is this one:

```
[
  {
    "status": "403",
    "title": "Authentication Failed",
    "userData": {},
    "ipRangeError": {
      "libraryName": "Name goes here",
     "libraryId": 657,
      "requestIp": "127.0.0.1"
    }
  }
]
```

If I remove the outermost enclosing `[]`, this error goes away.  I can't be the only person using an array as the top level entity of a JSON file in Swift 3, am I doing something wrong?  What can I do to get around this error?

Comment: Of course you can use an array as the top-level JSON object. But then you must treat it as an array, not as a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is referenced in the comments, the problem is that `getJSONDictionaryFromFile` returns an `NSDictionary *` and my JSON input is an array.  The only mystery is why this used to work in Swift 2.2!  I ended up changing `expectedResponseJSON` to be an `Any?`, and rewrote my Objective C code in Swift:

```
class func getStringFrom(file fileName: String, fileExtension: String) -> String {
    let filepath = Bundle(for: BZTestCase.self).path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileExtension)
    return try! NSString(contentsOfFile: filepath!, usedEncoding: nil) as String
}

class func getJSONFrom(file fileName: String) -> Any? {
    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (getStringFrom(file: fileName, fileExtension: ".json").data(using: .utf8))!, options:.allowFragments)
    return json
}
```

As a note to anyone who might cut and paste this code, I used `try!` and `filepath!` instead of `try?` and `if let...` because this code is used exclusively in tests, so I want it to crash as soon as possible if my inputs are not what I expect them to be.